# Why is the CSS not loading in Joomla 2.5.6?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I recently migrated my Joomla website from localhost to the test-server and after having completed the database imports and configurations(in configuration.php), the css doesn't seem to load although I can see that the css files have the correct privileges[644]. all I can see is mis-aligned text.

At first, I thought that since my template was custom, the problem lies in it but when I logged into administrator, the same problem occured, although here the text seems properly aligned.

The link to my website is : [www.wdwdi.com/calderoni](http://www.wdwdi.com/calderoni)

Please assist.

Comment: can you just give a link here so that I can have a look at it

Comment: Have you checked already on which file path the browser looks for the CSS?

Comment: @lars k. yes I have check the path, and have tried to eplicitly access it too.

Comment: @MukundZare The path was correct, and the CSS file could be loaded from the URL the browser was looking at? This is all frontend work, ok?

Comment: please provide a website link. It's hard to tell waht the problem is without viewing anything

Comment: Your stylesheets are loading, you have a different problem. I would definitely move the site using Akeeba as mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try the migration again with [AkeebaBackup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/) and the corresponding Kickstart-Script. It never failed in my usage. This will save your time you would use now for debugging.