# Why is css missing on contact page of Joomla 2.5.19 site?

Tags: css, forms, joomla, contacts

Affected page http://www.pawsingoodcare.com/contact-us. Other pages render correctly. Issue consistent across browsers. The page is not an 'article' but a contact form using RS Forms Pro. Nothing in their forums to suggest anything helpful.

I viewed this [Why is the CSS not loading in Joomla 2.5.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700514/why-is-the-css-not-loading-in-joomla-2-5-6) and other pages but none seem applicable.

I do not know when when this issue began. I had not done any editing of this page for many months and when I had finished that editing it worked well.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: your link gives 404 error.

Comment: Thanks.Didn't with me but if it does use: <http://www.pawsingoodcare.com/> then go to 'contact us'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick scan in your head, there are a few errors that aappear to be added by the plugin you are using. You may be better off using a different extension or doing some work in the plugin php files from the plugin.

But so far, I noticed it re-wrote your head declarations as such

```
<style charset="utf-8" type=\"text/css"\>
```

I cleaned a few out in the inspector. But the mess is huge. I think youa re better off using a different contact form extension or using the contact module that comes with Joomla to create the form

Comment: Thanks. Wonder how that happened? Did work well last time I edited it.... Will try out Joomla's contact module.  I've used ChonoForms on another site but seems overkill here.

Comment: you can use othe form component like `chronoform` and `Breezingforms` they both are really great component to build the form.

Comment: Listen, Joomla is super heavy. Every extension you add, you pack your site with more jqueries and unncessary scripts and stylesheets. Keep it small. Use the contact module that came with Joomla :)

Comment: This is Joomla 2.5. Not seeing a contact us component until Joomla 3. edit: I see a Contact Info Module. Assume this is what you mean. Will give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't worked with Joomla 2.5 in a while but I remember using the contact module. It will use the information you input in the contact info part of the global settings. On that note, would you consider this question answered?

Comment: Close... but I'm not seeing how to use the module to create a contact us form yet

Comment: That would be the answer to a different question. Try asking how to create a contact form in Joomla 2.5 without using an extension. The reason why I can't answer it here is because I will need to show you code. and I can't do it in this window, nor can I do it in the main window because I answered your main question there already :)

Comment: Will do.  Then consider this answered. Thank you LOTUSMS for your guidance. Also, thank you @Kheema Pandy - I may resort to using one of your suggestions but prefer working towards keeping site light.

Comment: @scottnsd ..lol to answer it, you need to check the answer check mark ;)

Comment: For completeness here, found good start via directions here: <http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla25/joomla25-contact-us-page.htm>

Comment: Sweet.  I'll check it out.  By the way, welcome to SO. You'll find that there are a lot of helpful people here and there are a lot of demeaning people who think they were born knowing code.